Bash dialog: chained command substitution if problem
I want to write a script based on dialog programbox (or others) and capture a command's stderr and the stdout passed to dialog into an array (if any), as well as the command's exit status (as last array element). For this, I'm using prepared command strings, command substitution and fd3 redirection.
Basically, this works nicely, as long as there're no chained commands with if involved - then I get error messages, like, in this case 'command not found'. Here's a (simplified) example:
# Prepare command strings
declare cmd0='if [[ -e . ]]; then echo TRUE; fi'
cmd1=($("$cmd0") 2>&1)
cmd2=(dialog --colors --no-collapse --programbox "\Zb\Z1List local folders..." 20 160)

# Redirect stdout and stderr to dialog, while executing cmd1 > cmd2, capturing cmd1 exit status
exec 3>&1
tmp=($(${cmd1[@]} 2>&1 | "${cmd2[@]}" 1>&3; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}))
exec 3>&-

# Print results
printf '%s\n' "${tmp[@]}"

The command declaration seems to require an array declaration, but then special chars like ';' will also add to the problem. This is what I tried; directly using c instead of cmd1 will print the whole line as error.
What needs to be changed, to make the command substituion for chained commands (including if) in cmd1 work?

Are you sure you don't want to define functions instead? (E.g. cmd0 () { if [[ -e . ]]; then echo TRUE; fi; }.

You need $(eval "$cmd0")

Shell syntax isn't parsed after expanding variables.

Don't store commands in variables. Variables are for storing data, functions are for storing commands. Variables get expanded partway through the command parsing process, so their values only get sort of half-parsed as shell syntax. If you use eval, they tend to get one-and-a-half-parsed, which has an annoying tendency to work fine in testing, then fail bizarrely sometime later. So just don't. See BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!" and many previous questions.

Does this answer your question? How can I store a command in a variable in a shell script?

Thank you for your input. The challenge specifically for the dialog programbox is, that I want to monitor any progress in realtime, without waiting for the command(s) to finish. Only then, the overall output should be stored in the var, which, in this case, would only be the command's exit status (not from the dialog). Perhaps there's a way to use tee, to also capture the pipe's data, but I haven't figured out by now, how. Plus, even if that works with dedicated functions each, that's going be a lot just for building the dialog commands and it'll be rather hard with nested commands.

While not completely 'anwering my question', some of the suggestions above, like moving the commands to process into a separate function each, have been acknowledged and applied in my (final) solution below. Other suggestions helped regarding the appropriate application of tee in the examples below. Depending on the use case, one of the partways or alternative solutions may work better, or suffice. The final solution, which addresses all requirements, uses a bit of everything, plus eval, though. Feel free to suggest improvements.

With the hints in the comments above I could come up with a solution, albeit not completely satisfactory, due to the need of defining functions for each complex/nested command to parse/pass to dialog programbox.
dialog_programbox can accept and parse simple commands via argument, or, for complex commands, process input from stdin instead:
There may be a way to extract piped input into the captured result var (here: exitStatus), e. g. per usage of tee - if someone knows, how, please feel free to post a solution.
For other dialog variants, which accept input from a var and which do not consume stdin, the output from dialog_programbox can be printed to stdout as newline-separated string, with exit/pipe status as the last or first element, for easy splitting from a captured result var. I'll probably extend the solution accordingly, at a later point.
# Function example for complex commands to pipe to dialog_programbox()
complexCmdFunc1() {
    # Requires explicit stderr redirection to stdout for each command
    # Could also split cmd execution and store exit status in var for reporting
    if ! git worktree remove -- "$1" 2>&1; then
        echo -e "\n\nREMOVAL BLOCKED:" "Worktree may not exist or is unlcean/locked (try force) - ABORTING."
        # Need to explicitly return exit status to report
        return 1
    fi
    echo -e "Successfully removed worktree:\n$1"
    return 0
}

dialog_programbox() {

    local -i height
    local -i width
    local -n cmd
    local cmdTmp
    local title
        
    for arg; do
        if [[ $arg == +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
            if [[ $height -gt 0 ]]; then
                width=$arg
                continue
            fi
            height=$arg
        elif [[ $title ]]; then
            if [[ -R $arg ]]; then
                cmd=$arg
            # For direct CMD arg injection, has bug
            elif ! declare -p "$arg" 2>&1 1>/dev/null; then
                cmdTmp=$arg
                cmd=cmdTmp
            elif [[ $(declare -p "$arg" 2>/dev/null) == 'declare -a'* ]]; then
                cmd=$arg
            elif [[ -z $cmd ]]; then
                cmd=$arg
            fi
        else
            title="$arg"
        fi  
    done
    
    [[ -z $height ]] && height=30
    [[ -z $width ]] && height=120

    # CMD ARG INJECTION
    if [[ $cmd ]]; then
        $( echo "${cmd[@]}" ) 2>&1 | dialog --title "$title" --colors --no-collapse --programbox $height $width 1>&3
        echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
        # stdin command substitution - would work but swallow pipe/exit status
        #dialog --title "$title" --colors --no-collapse --programbox $height $width 1>&3 < <($( echo ${cmd[@]} ) 2>&1)
    # PIPING STDIN
    else
        dialog --title "$title" --colors --no-collapse --programbox $height $width </dev/stdin 1>&3
        # Temp var would address empty stdin but waste real-time progress report
        #local tmp="$(grep . </dev/stdin)"
        # if [[ $tmp ]] ; then
            # dialog --title "$title" --colors --no-collapse --programbox $height $width <<<"$tmp"
        # else
            # echo 'Nothing to process.' | dialog --title "$title" --colors --no-collapse --programbox $height $width
        # fi
    fi
}

# COMPLEX CMD output piping usage - requires explicit echo of PIPESTATUS
exitStatus1=$(complexCmdFunc1 'unreleased' | dialog_programbox '\Zb\Z1Deleting local worktree...' 20 160; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]})

# More efficient, since no additional subshell invocation is needed:
complexCmdFunc1 'unreleased' | dialog_programbox '\Zb\Z1Deleting local worktree...' 20 160
exitStatus2=${PIPESTATUS[0]}

# Empty pipe, will render an empty dialog, of which addressing would require storing cmd result in temp var and losing real-time progress reporting
#exitStatus=$(echo | dialog_programbox '\Zb\Z1Deleting local worktree...' 20 160; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]})

# CMD var injection examples (for simple/non-nested commands)
#declare -a c=(ls foo bar)
declare c='ls foo bar'
exitStatus3=$(dialog_programbox '\Zb\Z1Deleting local worktree...' c 20 160)

# direct CMD injection - HAS BUG
#exitStatus=$(dialog_programbox '\Zb\Z1Deleting local worktree...' 'ls foo bar' 20 160)

echo -e "EXIT_STATUS1: $exitStatus1"
echo -e "EXIT_STATUS2: $exitStatus2"
echo -e "EXIT_STATUS3: $exitStatus3"

Another solution, based on this answer from Michał Górny (thanks), an example, on how to get the exit status AND the (displayed) output from a command defined in a function and processed by dialog programbox, involving coproc and global vars:
# Result array for storing processed command's output
declare -ga cmdOutput
declare -g exitStatus
worktreeName='unreleased'

# Command to process and get exit status + results from
gitRemoveWtCmd() {
    _IFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'
    cmdOutput=( $(git worktree remove -- "$worktreeName" 2>&1) )
    exitStatus=$?
    IFS="$_IFS"
    if [[ $exitStatus -ne 0 ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "${cmdOutput[@]}"
        echo -e "\nCannot remove unclean or non-existent worktree" 
    else
        echo -e "\nSuccessfully removed worktree: [$worktreeName]"; 
    fi
}

# Co-process with dialog to send command results to, redirected output to fd3
coproc diaProgramboxCop { 
    dialog --colors --no-collapse --programbox '\Zb\Z1List local folders...' 20 160 1>&3
}

# Redirecting processed stderr to output and linking fd3 there
{ exec 3>&1
  gitRemoveWtCmd 2>&1
  exec 3>&-
} >&${diaProgramboxCop[1]}

exec {diaProgramboxCop[1]}>&-
wait ${diaProgramboxCop_PID}

printf '%s%s\n' "OUTPUT: " "${cmdOutput[@]}"
echo -e "EXIT_STATUS: $exitStatus"

A real drawback here is, that global vars are required for cmdOutput and exitStatus and the capturing of the command's output eradicates the real-time displaying of the command's progress, due to storing it via subshell into the var before actually sending it to the dialog.
So, this approach would better be used with widgets like msgbox, which consume a pre-filled var.
According to the suggestion here, using fd3, redirected from tee + cat in a pipe, can be used for channelling all command output to the var assignment (stdout and stderr) and together with redirection of the dialog output directly to /dev/tty, this is another way of capturing the processed command's output, while displaying it via dialog in real-time, provided, the commands can be hard-coded and it can even return the no direct pipe/exit status:
worktreeName='unreleased'

_IFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'
cmdOutput=( $({ gitRemoveWtCmd ${worktreeName@Q} 2>&1 | tee >(cat >&3) | dialog_programbox '\Zb\Z1Deleting local worktree...' 20 120 >/dev/tty;} 3>&1 ; echo -e ${PIPESTATUS[0]}) )
printf '%s\n%s\n' "CMD_OUTPUT:" "${cmdOutput[@]:0:((${#cmdOutput[@]} - 1))}"
echo -e "EXIT_STATUS: ${cmdOutput[@]: -1}"
IFS="$_IFS"

The PIPESTATUS can still be printed from within the command substitution, but needs to be split off the captured output. But it's even better, to just use ;exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} from within the same process substitution curly braces, do without array splitting and simply use the exit status code from $? immediately in the next line.
The final solution allows the application of varying commands to the dialog, per use of eval inside the function getDialogCmdResultAndExitStatus(), which accepts a flag to silence any tty or stdout output and a var or name reference for the command to process and the dialog command to use for displaying, while by default also passing all command output to stdout (for capturing into a var) and always returning the processed command's internal pipe status as exit status, to enable follow-up decisions in scripts:
getDialogCmdResultAndExitStatus() {

    local quiet
    if [[ $1 =~ ^-[[:alnum:]] ]]; then
        if [[ ${1^^} != '-Q' ]]; then
            echo -e "Invalild argument: $1"
            exit 1
        fi
        quiet='TRUE'
        shift
    fi
    
    local -a com
    local -n cRef
    if ! declare -p "$1" &>/dev/null; then 
        com="$1"
    else
        cRef=$1
        com="${cRef[@]}"
    fi
    
    local -a diaCom
    local -n diaComRef
    if ! declare -p "$2" &>/dev/null; then 
        diaCom="$2"
    else
        diaComRef=$2
        diaCom="${diaComRef[@]}"
    fi
    
    if [[ $quiet ]]; then
        { eval "${com[@]@E} 2>&1" | eval "${diaCom[@]@E} >/dev/tty"; return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}; } 3>&1
    else
        { eval "${com[@]@E} 2>&1" | tee >(cat - >&3) | eval "${diaCom[@]@E} >/dev/tty"; return ${PIPESTATUS[0]}; } 3>&1
    fi
}

Used like this - using the processed command's exit status (internally pipe status) requires inline-usage together with if or capturing $? for further scripting decisions, right after the output capturing line:
# Prepare commands (utilizing functions from examples above)
declare command="gitRemoveWtCmd ${worktreeName@Q}"
declare dialogCmd="dialog_programbox '\Zb\Z1Deleting local worktree...' 20 120"

# Store and limit IFS to newlines
_IFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'
# Capture command's stdout and stderr + real-time displaying with dialog
cmdOutput=( $(getDialogCmdResultAndExitStatus command dialogCmd) )
# First line after output capturing: get pipe/exit status of processed command
echo -e "EXIT_STATUS: $?"
# Restore IFS to defaults
IFS="$_IFS"

or
if ! getDialogCmdResultAndExitStatus command dialogCmd; then
    # do sth else...
fi


The internal eval command might still be impvroved, suggestions welcome.
